# List the distinct principal ideals in $\mathbb{ℤ}_2 \times \mathbb{ℤ}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

How do I find and list the distinct principal ideals in $\mathbb{ℤ}_2\times\mathbb{ℤ}_3$?

I know that $\mathbb{ℤ}_2$ has $0,1$ and that $\mathbb{ℤ}_3$ has $0,1,2$, but I'm not sure how to list them and how to find ideals in $\mathbb{ℤ}_2\times\mathbb{ℤ}_3$.

Comment: Isn't this a field? Then the ideals are (0) and (1).

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure it is.

Comment: No, it's not a field - it has zero divisors, like $(0,1)$. But a principal idea consists of all products of a fixed element $a$ in the ring with all elements of the ring. There are only $6$ possibilities for $a$, so you just need to go ahead and calculate them all.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yeah you are right. My fault.

Comment: so, (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2) are the 6, correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First, find the six elements of $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3.$ Next, determine the principal ideals generated by each element. Some of them will generate the same principal ideal.

Comment: so, (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2) are the 6, correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Ok, now I don't know what to do with them.  Can you get me started?

Comment: Well, how do we find the principal ideal generated by a given element?

Comment: multiply by an "r" to generate multiples?

Comment: That's the idea!

Comment: so (r0,r0) = (0,0), etc, then look at what are congruent and group them?

Comment: You seem to have the right idea, but I can't tell from your phrasing. Feel free to run your solutions by me.

Comment: would I take any number in Z2 and multiply each of the 6 by that to see what it looks like as Z2xZ3, like r=1: (0*1,0*1)=(0,0)?  or would I multiply each pair to see what happens?  like (0,0)*(0,1)=(0*0,0*1)=(0,0)

Comment: I'll do one for you. Let's start with $a=(0,2)$. We have to multiply this by each of the six elements of the ring, which you listed above, and the six answers are $(0,0),(0,2),(0,1),(0,0),(0,2),(0,1)$, so the principal ideal generated by $a$ contains the three elements $(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)$. You have to do the same for all $6$ elements of the ring. You may sometimes find that different $a$ generate the same ideal.